# CSS Google Ad positiong

Tags: html, css, adsense

I have a problem where my Google Ad is pushing down the rest of my menu, even though my Google ad is in a div

```
.google {
    z-index:100000;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
}
```

I have some other divs that you can see, but I can't figure it out.

the site is http://www.rankmc.com

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `float:left;` to your `div.logo` rule.